# How to split numbers and text from a sentence?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string

I have a sentence that is mixed with numbers (integer and float), and often merged with other words. I want to separate the numbers and text and put it as a sentence.

The following does some work.

```
str1 = str1="test1.25nb 5test .5NB 00.5my_test 5unit 5.6"
re.findall(r'\d*\.*\d+\.*\d*', str1)
re.split(r'\d*\.*\d+\.*\d*',  str1)
```

However, I could not figure out a better way that gives a result nicely.

```
Input: str1="test1.25nb 5test .5NB 00.5my_test 5unit 5.6"

Expected output: test 1.25 nb 5 test .5 NB 00.5 my_test 5 unit 5.6"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there more of these strings, and if so, do they follow a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
str1 = "test1.25nb 5test .5NB 00.5my_test 5unit 5.6"
print( " ".join(re.split(r'\s*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*', str1)) )
# => test 1.25 nb 5 test .5 NB 00.5 my_test 5 unit 5.6
```

Or, directly using `re.sub` with `strip()` at the end:

```py
print( re.sub(r'\s*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*', r' \1 ', str1).strip() )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XsBc0v). The `\s*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*` regex matches

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d*\.?\d+)` - captures into Group 1 (and hence these values are also present in the resulting list produced with `re.split`) zero or more digits, an optional `.` and one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JReHxa/1).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not tied to regular expressions, this may be a bit easier to understand:

```
import string

str1 = "test1.25nb 5test .5NB 00.5my_test 5unit 5.6"
cnt = len(str1)
str2 = ""
numdigits = string.digits + "."

print(str1)
for i, c in enumerate(str1):
    str2 += c
    if i < cnt - 1:
        nextc = str1[i + 1]
        if c in numdigits and nextc in string.ascii_letters or c in string.ascii_letters and nextc in numdigits:
            str2 += " "
print(str2)
```

The basic logic is simple: for each character, peak at the next char, and see if there is a change between alphabetic and numeric status. If so, insert a space.

Note that the `enumerate(list)` built-in function returns a pair of values, an index value followed by the next element of the list. This can simplify the indexing process within a loop.